# html number list inside of a div?

Tags: html

So imagine you have two div tags side by side, one floats to the left the other to the right.

what I'd like to do, it create just a list of numbers down the page in the first div on the left. So that no matter how long the page or div gets vertically, the number list is created within that skinny div. I included a picture of what it would look like.

I've searched online but I don't know how to explain it to google? it offers up everything else that I don't understand. Does anyone have an idea as to where I would even start?

[Red arrow is what I'm wanting to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Wa2.png)

I found this on w3school about the counter-increment and i could use this but can this be done without the need to make all those h2 tags down the skinny div

[image]

Comment: Does using an `ol` an option? If not, you would need to use CSS or JavaScript. If those are valid options for you, please retag the question.

Comment: i see what the ol tag would do but i still need to create each number myself the issue is i don't know how long the div tag is going to be so i don't know how many to make, if it was generated on the fly with in that div it would fill it up or down the div for me

Comment: I am not sure I understand. How are you generating your divs?

Comment: the div is made by the forum software that I'm using, i was just going to kick the main div over to the right and add a new div on the left and then within that new div generate these numbers down the div

Comment: Can you use JS?

Comment: i don't see why not but that way outside of my knowhow

Answer (score 1):

One approach to achieving this effect would be to add an empty ordered list (`<ol>`) to the end of your markup:

```
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

This `<ol>` can be absolutely positioned down the left-hand side of the viewport, while an element like `<main>` (which contains the rest of the content) can be given a `margin-left` to accommodate it.

The 0-prefixed numbers can be added to the `<ol>` using a combination of `content` and the CSS `counter()` function.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
:root {
  color: rgb(0, 191, 0);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

main {
  margin: 0 42px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

ol {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: count;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  counter-increment: count;
}

li::before {
  content: '00' counter(count, decimal-leading-zero);
}
```

```html
<main>
<h1>Body Content Here</h1>
<p>The numbers to the left are absolutely positioned.</p>
<p>The main part of your content can go here.</p>
</main>

<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter()

Comment: the problem is i have to create all those li /li tags all the way down the page and i don't know how long the div will be on this page, it a forum and i'm adding a number line down the left side but some forum pages are longer then others

Comment: honestly i was thinking of just making a super long image of these numbers and then putting that image in that div s background and doing a hide overflow to see if that would work, thats my quick and dirty method, lol

Comment: basically if i could generate a list of numbers to say from 1 to 1000 or 2000 and have that list run down that shinny div that what work fine, maybe like a random number gen but in order, i added a pic to the main question of what i've found its close

Comment: @Rounin https://stackoverflow.com/a/70118183/14807111

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Rounin answer, I adapted it further and made it a little javascript dynamic.

```js
document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  t = document.getElementById('i');
  lines = t.value.split("\n").length;
  let _m = document.getElementById('m');
  _m.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < lines; i++) {    
    let l = document.createElement('li');
    _m.append(l)
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  color: rgb(0, 191, 0);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

main {
  margin: 0 52px;  
}

ol {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: count;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  counter-increment: count;
}

li::before {
  content: '00' counter(count, decimal-leading-zero);
}

textarea {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top:5px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none;  
}
```

```html
<body id="c">
<main>
  <textarea id="i">type something</textarea>
</main>

<ol id="m">
  <li class="mli"></li>
</ol>
</body>
```

Comment: Good work, @MaikLowrey. (I'm not sure this is the kind of thing the OP is looking for, but I *really* like it!)

Answer (score 0):

You'd essentially need to `left-align` and then use a generic numbered list such as:

```
<div id="list-left">
  <div class="list"><span id="001">001</span></div>
  <div class="list"><span id="002">002</span></div>
  <div class="list"><span id="003">003</span></div>
  <div class="list"><span id="004">004</span></div>
  <div class="list"><span id="005">005</span></div>
</div>
```

I can't remember the exact steps, but hopefully this is a good starting point for you.

Comment: but I would have to create a whole list of numbers is there a way to dynamically generate them on the fly?

Comment: its like i want to generate a random set of number down that div but in order, 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#counters) - try using this and see if it helps.

Comment: how to i add code examples here i found something on w3school about what you offered and i made a small change to it but how do i show you the code here?

Answer (score 0):

You can put dose two div's in a div, make that div "display: flex" and just add width to the left div so it won't expand horizontally. That's it i guess after you do that just experiment and see what will work for you.

Comment: I understand what your saying and that would work for creating the divs but what about the numbering down the side?

Comment: You can make a Ul and style like "display: flex; flex-direction: column" this will orient it vertically then just style list items like "width: 100%;" and add height, padding or margin experiment see what works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I figured it out and this is what i came up with. I couldn't of done it without you all's help. I'd post the code itself but it doesn't seem to be a straight forward task here, (I'm new to this place, so I don't know how to navigate and do all the things here you guys know how to do in posting stuff. So I'm just posting pics of what I got.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: but there is a problem with this approach and that is that although it works, if I try and put this list of numbers in a skinny div on the left and the numbers are like up to 200 or 500 long it makes that div that long. while the div on the right is short. I'm trying this out on a forum and the right div is the forum content which changes height as the content changes but the left div is static and is as long as the numbers are. so there is this large gap at the bottom of the right div if the content is not that long. I thought maybe something like hide over flow would work but it doesn't.